# Queue api calls in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to make more than two api calls one by one only after the result of the called one.And all the three api calls have same result fetch method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible option is to use `NSOperationQueue`.

Do it in following steps:

1. Get the NSOperationQueue. Visit this for further details.
   http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html
2. Make NSOperation. here is class reference of NSOperation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html
3. Add dependency of previous operation in current operation using `- (void)addDependency:(NSOperation *)operation` method.
4. Add operation to queue.

Dependency of first operation will invoke second only after first completes.